# 301 redirects from a flash site (.swf) to wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, flash, redirect

I am trying to get 301 redirect to work from an old flash site to new wordpress site.

If I place

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com
```

it redirects everything; however new urls are different than old ones.

So I would get a lot of 404's.

For instance:

```
Redirect 301 /oldlink.swf http://newsite.com/old-link
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try RedirectMatch directive with regex to pass old path to a new :

```
 RedirectMatch 301 /([^.]+).swf$ http://newsite.com/newurl
```

This will redirect old http://oldsite.com/foo.swf to http://newsite.com/newurl

Comment: Thanks Starkeen...we do not wish to redirect to a new SWF file though but to a WP URL

Comment: I've tried that all ready but the thing is the new domain has a different url so before url was /somepage.swf . New url can be http://newlocation/newurl

Comment: Thanks. It works, it redirects all urls to the new url . But how do I redirect specific url to a specific url. I have 30+ url that need to be redirected to different url's respectively. 

How can I redirect 

oldsite/url1.swf to newsite/newurl1
oldsite/url2.swf to newsite/url-new-21